# Why routes are not working in laravel-livewire?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I am working having laravel-livewire. In my project route are not working.

Here the route list..

```
<?php

use App\Http\Livewire\HomeComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\ShopComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\CartComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\CheckoutComponent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/',HomeComponent::class);

Route::get('/shop',ShopComponent::class);

Route::get('/cart',CartComponent::class);

Route::get('/checkout',CheckoutComponent::class);
```

From the above route only 1st route work properly.But the rest are not working.
They shows 404(Not Found).

Here I am giving 2nd route componet and resource materials.

ShopComponent

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Livewire;
 use Livewire\Component;

class ShopComponent extends Component
{
 public function render()
 {
    return view('livewire.shop-component')->layout('layouts.base');
 }
}
```

Shop-component.blade.php

```
<div>
Shop Page
</div>
```

Why the code not working?
Here the screenshoot of the problem..
[image]

Comment: Are the routes showing up correctly if you do `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: @Peppermintology, the routes do not show correctly.

Comment: Therein lies your problem. Where are you defining your routes?

Comment: Routes directory: Demoecommerce>routes>web.php

Comment: Try clearing your route cache. If you can't see them in `route:list` then something is preventing them from being registered.

Comment: Alhamdulillah,now the code is running properly.Thanks you very much.May Allah show you the right path.

Comment: Have you included the component with `@livewireStyles` and `@livewireScripts` for the shop component to be rendered? could be the problem why you have 404 pages not found.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have some routing problem. Probably this caused by route caching. Laravel route caching is used to drastically decrease the amount of time it takes to register all of your application's routes ([Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-caching)). What you need to keep in mind is when you cache your route changes made to your routes file will not update automatically so you need to remove your cache by running

```
php artisan route:clear
```

or reset your cache by running

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Lastly, to view your route list run the command below

```
php artisan route:list
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Livewire 1. x allowed you to register a component with a route for the entire page using the Route::livewire() method. Livewire 2.0 now allows you to pass Livewire components directly into routes using the standard Route::get() method and the fully qualified namespace.

[https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/upgrading#:~:text=11%7D-,Removed%3A%20Route%3A%3Alivewire(),-Livewire%201.x](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/upgrading#:%7E:text=11%7D-,Removed%3A%20Route%3A%3Alivewire(),-Livewire%201.x)

// Before
**Route::livewire('/post', 'show-posts');**

// After
**Route::get('/post', \App\Http\Livewire\ShowPosts::class);**